# PInvoke Unbalances the stack

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke

Good afternoon,

I have been working on a dll that can use CORBA to communicate to an application that is network aware.  The code works fine if I run it as a C++ console application.  However, I have gotten stuck on exporting the methods as a dll.  The methods seems to export fine, and if I call a method with no parameters then it works as expected.  I'm hung up on passing a C# string to a C++ method.

My C++ method header looks like this:

```
bool __declspec(dllexport) SpiceStart(char* installPath)
```

My C# DLL import code is as follows:

```
[DllImportAttribute("SchemSipc.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Ansi)]
private static extern bool SpiceStart(string installPath);
```

I call the method like so:

```
bool success = SpiceStart(@"c:\sedatools");
```

The call to SpiceStart throws the exception "PInvokeStackImbalance", which "is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature."

Does anyone have any suggestions?  If I remove the char* and string from the parameters, then the method runs just fine.  However, I'd like to be able to pass the installation path of the application to the dll from C#.

Thanks in advance,

Giawa

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The calling conventions don't match.  In C++, declare the function with the stdcall calling convention:

extern "C" bool __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall SpiceStart(char* installPath)

Comment: +1.  Or specify the calling convention in the DllImportAttribute.

Comment: Perfect - That did the job!  Thanks